# Angular: data validation through event event

Tags: angular, typescript, events

in angular i have a child component to get input from user and send it to server via rest apis, however my child component want to validate data from parent  component through event,  before sending data to server. How can parent component cancell sending if data is not valid.

i want a variable in event like event.cancel and if the cancel if parent component set value of cancel = true then component do send data to server